# Getting compile error: int[][] cannot be converted to int Java

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, compiler-errors

The problem should be in calculateMainDiagonal method, The compile error I get is:

> int[][] cannot be converted to int        int sumD1 =
>   calculateMainDiagonal(m);

Now main should stay the same as it's my professor code. Any help will be appreciated. I believe I'm suppose to return a int, but I am not sure.

Attempts I tried:

> public static int [][] calculateMainDiagonal(int sum);
>
> public static int [][] calculateMainDiagonal(int [][] sum);
>
> public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int sum)

When i input this:

> public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int [][] sum);

it gives me this compile error instead:

> java:50: error: missing method body, or declare abstract  public
>   static int calculateMainDiagonal(int [][] sum);

```
public class TesterProject
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int n = getMatrixSize();
        int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);
        printMatrix(m);

        int sumD1 = calculateMainDiagonal(m);
        System.out.println("The sum of the main diagonal is " + sumD1);
    }
    public static int getMatrixSize()
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
        int n = S.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
    public static int [][] makeAndFillMatrix(int n)
    {
        Random generator = new Random(5);
        int [][] r = new int[n][n];
        int rand = generator.nextInt(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < r[i].length; j++)
            {
                r[i][j]= rand;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
    public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    //only problem is this method
    public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int sum);
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < total; r++)
        {
            total += r;
        }
        return total;
}
```

}

Comment: The line that declares `calculateMainDiagonal` has an extra semicolon in it.

Comment: Also, don't call the parameter `sum`.  You're computing a value from a matrix.  The matrix is the parameter, not the sum.

Comment: OMG, I am so dumb... I was working on it for hours lol. I can't believe I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad semicolon, and your parameter is an `int[][]` (not an `int`).

```
public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int[][] m) // <-- no semicolon.
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < m.length; r++) // <-- not r < total.
    {
        if (r < m[r].length) {
            total += m[r][r];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semicolon at the end of `calculateMainDiagonal(int m)` and change the parameter into `calculateMainDiagonal(int[][] m) { ... }`.

You also need to modify your `for` loop in that method as well, as it does not take into consideration the parameter.

Something like:

```
public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int[][] matrix) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        total += matrix[r][r];
    }
    return total;
}
```